# VSCode - Can a task call another task?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Vscode Version: 1.19.3

I was wondering if there was a way for one task to call another, like the "preLaunchtask" but for regular tasks.

The reason is because when I want debug my code, I need to recompile my executable to the latest version so I have the "preLaunchTask" call the CMakeTask which then needs to call make, to make my executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Overall**

Yes, you can automatically call custom scripts for other languages, though not yet for C. From the [task docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks),

> VS Code currently auto-detects tasks for the following systems: Gulp,
>   Grunt, Jake and npm. We are working with the corresponding extension
>   authors to add support for Maven and the C# dotnet command as well. If
>   you develop a JavaScript application using Node.js as the runtime, you
>   usually have a package.json file describing your dependencies and the
>   scripts to run.

**For C (or other custom)**

You'll want to define a custom task as in the build task group so that it's run there.

> Not all tasks or scripts can be auto-detected in your workspace.
>   Sometimes it is necessary to define your own custom tasks. Assume you
>   have a script to run your tests since it is necessary to setup some
>   environment correctly. The script is stored in a script folder inside
>   your workspace and named test.sh for Linux and macOS and test.cmd for
>   Windows. Run Configure Tasks from the global Tasks menu. This opens
>   the following picker.

You can make an entirely arbitrary command as long as your system recognizes the binary to use, and it can be a powershell, bash, batch, etc script that calls your build steps in order. This could be a command listing other commands or you could simply add multiple arbitrary tasks to this build group.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run tests",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./scripts/test.sh",
            "windows": {
                "command": ".\\scripts\\test.cmd"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As the default build task it is executed directly when triggering Run Build Task (Ctrl+Shift+B).

**Task property notes:**

- **label**: The tasks's label used in the user interface.
- **type**: The task's type. For a custom task, this can either be shell or process. If shell is specified, the command is interpreted as a shell command (for example: bash, cmd, or PowerShell). If process is specified, the command is interpreted as a process to execute. If shell is used, any arguments to the command should be embedded into the command property to support proper argument quoting. For example, if the test script accepts a --debug argument then the command property would be: ./scripts/test.sh --debug.
- **command**: The actual command to execute.
- **windows**: Any Windows specific properties. Will be used instead of the default properties when the command is executed on the Windows operating system.
- **group**: Defines to which group the task belongs. In the example, it belongs to the test group. Tasks that belong to the test group can be executed by running Run Test Task from the Command Palette.
- **presentation**: Defines how the task output is handled in the user interface. In this example, the Integrated Terminal showing the output is always revealed and a new terminal is created on every task run.

Comment: This is perfect! I forgot all about creating my own shell script to handle all the grunt work. This is definitely going to save me a lot of work.

Answer (score 30):

You can make it depends on another task. Example:

```
    {
        "label": "secondTask",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "<Your second task's command here>",
        "dependsOn": [
            "firstTask"
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "firstTask",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "<Your first task's command here>"
    }
```

Comment: This (or Badr Elmers') should be the accepted answer. I am gonig with yours since you provided an example. And the cool thing about `dependsOn` is that you can specify a list of tasks. And what is even cooler is that you can also use `dependsOrder` to define if they will be executed in sequence or in paralell. It is great for C/C++ programmers because you can just define a "build" task, a "clean" task and then you can create a "rebuild" task and just say it depends on the "clean" and "build" tasks.

Comment: Thanks @user1593842 i didn't know that dependsOrder parameter, it is usefull too. Like you've said i'm using for "maven build" but before that i'm running a "clean" job.

Comment: Hello, do you know if there is a way to make workspace tasks depend on user tasks? I cannot find any doc, link or issue. I just get the error `Couldn't resolve dependent task 'task name' in workspace folder`

Answer (score 15):

> Chaining tasks is possible. use "dependsOn": ['Build'] in task Deploy.
>   [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48818)

Comment: Your answer is good, please just update it and provide an example.

Comment: Don't forget `"dependsOrder": "sequence"`, which is probably desired.